Flag searcher - search in your flagging history
I don't know any good way to search for your own flags by custom accept/rejection reasons, title, flag text or detailed flag type (e.g. "Not an Answer") hence I wrote a user script for that purpose.
How to use
When you go to your flag history, you should see a button with the text "Search flags" below the "Your flagging history" sidebar:

When clicking that button, you will be prompted to enter a search string. After confirming that, it goes through all pages of your flagging history (with the current filters being applied) and shows you all your flags matching that search string instead of the normal flag history. For this, it checks the (text) content of the entire flag history entry.
Setup
The script is available on GitHub:
view install
